# Is there a way to set default binding option in base class?

Tags: wpf, binding, idataerrorinfo

I have MyTextBox which is derived from TextBox. I want to set Binding Option ValidatesOnDataErrors = True of TextProperty in MyTextBox so that whenever I use this control ValidatesOnDataErrors is initialized with True.

This is my code :

```
public class MyTextBox:MyBaseTextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        MaxLength = 45;
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (e.Property == TextProperty)
        {
            Binding b = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this, TextProperty);
            if (b != null)
            {
                b.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

And I always get the exception :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is special binding not special textbox.

Have a look here: [Set ValidatesOnDataErrors for all bindings programmatically](http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/set-validatesondataerrors-for-all-bindings-programmatically-24837.shtml)

in WPF you can't change binding once it has been used.

to make your code work you'd have to clear the binding first and then add a new one with ValidatesOnDataErrors set to true, but that sounds like a messy way...